# anaconda error "HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/current_repodata.json>"

Tags: python, linux, docker, http, anaconda

I want to implement this repository : https://github.com/abedavis/visbeat
To do so, I am running a docker file as mentioned in the README.MD file of the repository using the command

> sudo docker build --build-arg http_proxy=172.16.2.30:8080 -t visbeat .

inside the 'docker' folder of the repository. Yes I am using proxied wifi.

**Expected results** : Docker image build succesfully

**Actual result** : Facing an error on the step 6 :-

> Step 6/14 : RUN conda create --quiet --yes -p $CONDA_DIR/envs/python2 python=2.7 ipython >ipykernel kernda &&     conda clean -tipsy
>   ---> Running in b7c3b4b1d5db
>   Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... failed
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/current_repodata.json
>   Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
>   HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>   'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64'
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c conda create --quiet --yes -p $CONDA_DIR/envs/python2 python=2.7 >ipython ipykernel kernda &&     conda clean -tipsy' returned a non-zero code: 1

**What I have tried** :

1) I have searched the error on Google and github.

2) I tried adding proxy that I am using in .condarc file.

None of the above solutions worked for me.

**To reproduce the problem** :

1) Clone the repository

2) Run the command to build the dockerfile. Give any sudo access if required.

Comment: Are you working on a corporate network?

Comment: @Foggy It's been some time since I have worked on that code. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is directly addressed in Anaconda's documentation, and here is their recommended solution. I am dealing with the same problem, and will post when I figured out how to fully implement it. Straight from Anaconda:

> Some corporate environments use proxy services that use
> Man-In-The-Middle (MITM) attacks to sniff encrypted traffic. These
> services can interfere with SSL connections such as those used by
> conda and pip to download packages from repositories such as PyPI.

-Ref: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/disable-ssl-verification.html

**Option 1: Insecure Solution**

One option, which I do not recommend for a permanent solution, is to turn off SSL verification. This makes you vulnerable to man in the middle attacks.

`conda config --set ssl_verify false`

Once you have downloaded the files you need, turn SSL back on:

`conda config --set ssl_verify true`

**Option2: Anaconda's Commercial Edition**

Again, this is straight from Anaconda's documentation and I am not a security expert. Anaconda's documentation is limited on this, but if you read the help documentation in conda (`conda token -h`) you will see that the `token` command is used to configure access for Anaconda Commercial.
Disable the SSL certificate so you can install the necessary library.

`conda config --set ssl_verify false`

Install `conda-token`, here it is going into the base environment:

`conda install conda-token -n base`

Ensure the token verification step ignores SSL errors, and replace `<token>` with your token. At the moment, :

`conda token set --no-ssl-verify <token>`

You will still see InsecureRequestWarning, but it is expected.

My network security team gave the CRT file for this step, but I received an error that the CRT `token couldn't be validated`.

To see if the token was accepted, use:

`conda token list`

Reference: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-professional/troubleshooting/#id5

**Option 3: Security Changes**

Contact your network security team to change the rules to allow conda to communicate with Anaconda without decrypting the traffic. This is the solution I ended up using.

Comment: It's been some time that I have worked on that code. Still, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @AkhilRaj - you are welcome. I was fighting with the same issues. Could you give me a vote if you like the answer?

Comment: @AkhilRaj - I am facing same issue, can you share the solution which worked for you